# What settings on light components actually work in Rec Room Studio?

Tags: unity, performance

In experimenting around with the Rendering settings for a spotlight, I've discovered that the `Culling Mask` does not actually apply when a room is built. Despite the editor showing it functioning just fine (as shown in the below image), once the build completes and I load up the room in Rec Room, the effects of the `Culling Mask` are not present.

[image: In Editor Photo]
[image: In Game Photo]

While it is easy for me to see that the `Culling Mask` is not taking effect, there are many other settings on the light component that aren't so easy to know if they're actually taking effect. When optimizing the room, it would be helpful to know what my options are.

For instance, `Render Mode` is one such setting that can have some impact on room performance. By default, lights have the "Auto" setting, but I would like to be certain that specific lights are "Not Important".

[image: Documentation describing the different render modes]

`Inner/Outer spot angle` is another setting that appears to work in the editor but does not get reflected in the final build of the room.

What settings on Light components actually affect the result of the build in Rec Room studio?

Comment: To elaborate on my comment on your earlier question - it doesn't hurt to ask, but questions about third-party assets often don't get answered. Unless the asset is very widely used, it's unlikely that your question will be found by someone who is familiar with the asset and knows the answer. You are much more likely to get answers from a community centered around the asset, such as official Reddit or Discord channels, while bug reports should generally go directly to the team that makes the asset.

Comment: Affirmative, I've also posted this question on their discord server and when I get an answer they'll either put the answer here or I'll put it here.